# Passing variables over from basket to Paypal for Payment - VAT charge

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I have my own basket which is built up based on what the user buys obviously. This then gets passed over to paypal checkout once the user clicks on checkout. It all works successfully with the item information being displayed in the PayPal cart receipt on the left hand side.

However, I am having an issue with my vat charge cost. I have calculated vat charge (20%) for my basket which works (within my site), but I am not sure how to pass that cost over to Paypal. Currently, Paypal are just calculating the total by adding the items prices depending on their quantities. Any ideas for getting the vat charge to be included in Paypal?

Here is my code:

```
$product1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);?>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number_<?php echo $count; ?>' value="<?php echo $count; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $product1['prod_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $count; ?>" value="<?php echo $product1['price']; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='quantity_<?php echo $count; ?>' value="<?php echo $item['quantity']?>">
<?php $count++; } ?>
```

And here is my shipping code for my basket:

```
$grand_total = isset($grand_total) ? $grand_total : 0;
  $line_cost = $product['price'] * $item['quantity'];
  $grand_total += $line_cost;
  $charge = $grand_total /100 * 20;
  $chargeincvat = $charge + $grand_total;

<tr><td colspan='6' align='right'>Charges (VAT 20%): &pound; <?=number_format($chargeincvat, 2);?></td></tr>
```

ADDED:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">

<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="business"

value="derrysnurseries@hotmail.co.uk">



<input type='hidden' name='item_number_1' value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Moment in Time">

<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="6.95">

<input type='hidden' name='quantity_1' value="1">

<input type='hidden' name='tax_cart' value="8.34">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can use the following as the `name` attribute of form elements :</strike>

```
shipping - applies to first item added to cart
shipping2 - applies to each additional item added to cart
handling_cart - applied once to cart regardless of quantity
```

for example

```
<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="15.00">
```

to apply a `15.00` total charge for shipping

To add tax / VAT to an item use `tax_#` where `#` is the item number eg

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_2" value=".15">
```

this will add `.15p` to item number 2. To add a cart tax / VAT use

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value=".15">
```

[See page 263 of this doc](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf) and see page 294 of the same document to have the tax / VAT cost automatically calculated

Comment: @user1278496 no probs ... see my update :-) if you search for tax instead of VAT you will have more joy ... VAT is UK only

Comment: Hey mate - it has kind of worked, except that paypal have calculated the VAT of the total and added it on (which is good) but then its added the total on top of that. EG - total is £171.95, 20% of that is £34.39 - it adds these together which makes £206.34 BUT THEN adds 171.95 (the total) on top of that...

Comment: @user1278496 I think the total is calculated for you ... are you also passing it ?

Comment: Nope I am not passing the total. The total is calculated but only within my site

Comment: @user1278496 strange ... can you add the HTML output of your form to the question - might be something obvious ....

Answer (score 0):

you can try sending the shipping info in

input type='hidden' name='shipping' value="25.93"

you can also check here : 
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables